# How to make coupled auto regressive time series

Tags: autoregressive

I am not an expert in statistics so sorry if it seems silly.
I am trying to reproduce the results of an [article](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0055809) which need to produce a coupled auto regressive time series with order 10:

$$
X(t+1) = \sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k X(t-k) +\sigma \eta_X(t), \\
Y(t+1) = \sum_{k=0}^m \beta_k Y(t-k) +\sigma \eta_Y(t) + g\sum_\delta X^2(t+1-\delta). \\
$$

where $m = 10$, $\sigma$ is noise and $\delta$ is delay.
The values for $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$ where constructed from roots of the characteristic polynomial of the the AR process, that were chosen at random on the unit circle to guarantee a stationary AR process (I don't get this part).

All I know from auto regressive process is that we always have a time series and use auto regressive to analyse the data, apply some prediction ...

How we can create some time series with given order which are coupled with some delay?
I tried to replace some random number instead of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ but the time series go to huge numbers.

**edit**

In other words the question is how to create time stationary time series with 10 significant auto regressive term, right?

Thanks in advance for any guide.

Comment: What is $g$? Also yes that is why they choose on unit circle ... to prevent "explosive proces" going to huge numbers as you say.

Comment: `g` is a coupling term and is constant. I don't know why unit circle. I tried also random numbers in [-1,1], normal random distribution with mean 0 and std =1, still the series diverge to huge numbers.

Comment: Hi: If you want to generate an AR(10) that doesn't explode, you need to use AR  coefficients such the roots of the associated characteristic equation are only satisfied when one is outside ( or inside depending on how one defines the characteristic equation ) the unit circle. I'm not clear on how you do that but that's how you would do it in theory.

Comment: At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/494445/919 I describe a general technique to create time series datasets with prescribed ACF functions.  It amounts to diagonalizing the covariance matrix.  Whether any term is "significant" in the usual sense (of a hypothesis test) depends on the size of the dataset as well as chance, so should we interpret "significant" as simply meaning "nonzero"?