Is it possible to describe repeating data patterns as a stochastic process?
Generally, can repetitive patterns in sensor readings (e.g. temperature measurements at different locations over time) be seen as some kind of stochastic process?
That is, if similar patterns repeat continuously at a fixed interval, is it correct to describe point-specific variability (at the same $i^\text{th}$ sample within each period) with a normal distribution across different repetitions?
My question stems from the fact that observations/samples are clearly not i.i.d. over time (there is an underlying repetitive temporal trend) but the process could be described as
$\{ X_i[k]:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for each $k^\text{th}$ repetition of the observed pattern.

Look for cyclostationary random processes especially in the signal processing and communication literature'

At https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410534 I construct a wide range of examples of such a process explicitly.  Generally, such "repetitive patterns" are referred to as seasonality in time series analysis.  There are standard methods to detect and characterize seasonality, such as those based in Fourier analysis of the autocovariance function (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16117) and others based on large lags: see SARIMA for instance.

@DilipSarwate indeed this was I was looking for; and the answer whuber linked does provide a good reference for the analysis of such signals; but in my particular case I was trying to formalize the stochastic aspect of the such processes, and not so much study the seasonality/autocorrelation (I already assume that seasonality from the start )
